# Which version of MPI is in MS-MPI v9.0.1

Tags: ms-mpi

I have been searching the internet to find the version of MPI in the Microsoft's MSMPI v9.0.1.

Is it MPICH1 (1.0, 1.1, 1.2 etc) or MPICH2 (2.1, 2.2) ? Does anybody know the full version number?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56727&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_extensions

Comment: There is no mention of version number